# Place Gtkmm Window at the center of one display when multiple screens are present

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gtk, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I have multiscreen ubuntu machine  which has screens arranged as follows

[image]

I need to place one Gtkmm window at **the center of Screen 3**.
For that, I calculate the center of the screen location and move the window in that location.

```
// let window size may (w,h) and Screen size may (W,H)
// let (X,Y) be the output
X = 0 + W/2 - w/2;
Y = 2160 + H/2 - h/2;
```

Here the window size (w,h) is predefined, sometimes the screen grows bigger than (w,h) because of bigger content. At that time window won't be at the center since we calculated with (w,h) and screen size is changed to (w', h') now.

I tried to get the updated size of the window by

```
this->signal_size_allocate().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &BaseWindow::windowShown));
```

But the window is shown at the wrong location and moved to the correct location immediately. This won't be an issue but sometimes there are a lot of window updates and looks like the window is moving back and forth.

So I would like to know what is the correct way to put a window at the center of a specified location (here screen 3) in Gtkmm way so that even though the window grows bigger, it should be at the center.

Comment: Which gtkmm version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Gtkmm-3.22.2-2